# Fail2ban adding new chain

Tags: fail2ban

how to create a new chain that appear in first position (before recidive) that create iptables rules to block an entire IP class if recidive has N IP's of that block?

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you change the firewall to CSF ConfigServer 
https://configserver.com/cp/csf.html
It is much more powerful and better for any type of customization.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Going to install as webmin module.

Comment: Very very useful!! Thank you again Doc!

Comment: It works like a charm! Country blocks, openvpn and the other stuff ...